# how to extract n rows from parquet in terminal

Tags: bash, parquet

I know one can use python or other scripting languages to extract `n` rows from parquet files. However I would like to do so in terminal.

I know there is a `parquet-tools` which one can execute through docker as following

```
docker container run \
    -v ${PWD}/data/users/:/data \
    --rm \
    -t rm3l/parquet-tools:latest \
    cat /data/date_partition=2023-02-27/0040_part_00.parquet
```

but the `cat` prints everything. I appreciate if you help me to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

I really don't know how to generate a dummy parquet file.

if I pipe the output to head as following

```
docker container run \
    -v ${PWD}/data/curated/bi.public.users/date_partition=2023-02-27/:/data \
    --rm \
    -t rm3l/parquet-tools:latest \
    cat data/0040_part_00.parquet | head -n 7
```

I get the following which is fine, but I would like the output to be `parquet` format

[image]

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I don't know how to generate a dummy parquet file.

Answer (score 0):

What about this (imagine you want to see lines 3-7 from a file):

```
head -n 7 file | tail -n $(7 - 3)
```

The `head` shows you the first seven lines, and the `tail` shows you the last four lines, because of which you get the desired result.

If you already have a command, producing the file, you might do the following:

```
... | head -n 7 | tail -n $(7 - 3)
```

Comment: Thankls @Dominique I have updated my question w.r.t your comment.